# In Visual C#, how to disable WiX project? (makes build too slow)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix

I am using Visual C# 2010.
I used to have a WiX script independently from Visual C#.
But recently I decided to integrate it as a WiX project inside Visual C#.

PROBLEM: Visual C# is now much slower when building.
Whenever I want to launch Debug it takes forever, and when there is a compilation error all sorts of WiX errors appear too.

Can I disable/close the WiX Project, and only enable it when I need it? (like in Eclipse)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, go to `Build` -> `Configuration Manager`

Here you can uncheck `Build` for your WiX project.

This way the project will not build. You can also choose to not build it in the `Debug` configuration but to have it build when doing a `Release` build.

Answer (score 0):

Almost exactly like Eclipse, right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and click unload.

Also like Eclipse (but Eclipse is a bit more complicated), you can have more than one solution that contains a common subset of projects.